# Lilypad USB not responding

Tags: arduino, usb

I played for the hole day with my Lilypad USB, and out of the blue it stopped working.
The port in the Arduino IDE is gray (even if i am running as an admin). The device is no more shown the /dev/ or in the device manager for window.

In windows when i plug the device is and push the reset button twice i can see the device under other devices but after a few second the device disappears.

How can i resolve this matter? Is there another hardware factory reset method?

Please help.

Comment: Consider posting your question on http://arduino.stackexchange.com/. Maybe you can get an answer there faster.

Answer (score 0):

hiduino answer from here helped
http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=153674.0;wap2